# Filtering arrays for use with UISearchBar

Tags: arrays, swift, uisearchbar

I have a table view which displays a user's Name, Company Name and Photo (PFFile). Each tableView row I have has all of this information in it.

I am using UISearchBarDelegate and IB to implement a search function to filter by the user's Name. It is finding the correct user but I have not been able to also update the company photo.

How do I filter the other arrays? The items I need from the arrays will be at the same index as the ones taken from the user's Name array.

EDIT: I am trying a different data structure and am receiving array index out of range, updated code below:

```
var filterArray = [User]()  //<-- globally declared
var userArray = [User]() //< Global


class User {

var name: String?
var company: String?

init (name: String?, company: String?) {

    self.name = name
    self.company = company
    }
}
//In a class which populates the search arrays
for object in unwrappedSucceeded {

   let username = object.valueForKey("username") as! String
   let companyName = object.valueForKey("companyName") as! String
   let user = User(name: username, company: companyName)

    userArray.append(user)
}

//tableViewController

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filterArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    if searchText.characters.count != 0 {
        isSearch = true

        self.search(searchText)

    } else {
        isSearch = false
    }
}


func search(text: String) -> Void {

    filterArray = userArray.filter({$0.name == text})

}
//In cellForRowAtIndexPath
            cell.usernameCell.text = filterArray[indexPath.row].name //ARRAY INDEX OUT OF RANGE
```

Comment: your best bet is to group each user info into  one container, therefore use an array of `struct` or `class` instead of having different arrays to contain each user's info

Comment: I agree but unfortunately my app is quite along with the current setup, I'd have to pretty much rebuild from scratch to implement it.

Comment: simply put: then you have to do that. If you do not do that you will get more and more problems that will take more and more time to fix - don't postpone important design fixes until it is definitely too late. At some point you have to "rebuild from scratch" - but the longer the wait the more stuff you have to "rebuild".

Comment: Ben check my answer, I try to give you a summarized answer..

Comment: That's really great, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said you strongly recommend to group each user's info into one big container, therefore we could use array of `struct` or `class`, then it comes easier to filter.

schematic for the container:

```
struct Container
{
  var username:String?
  var companyName:String?
  var photo:UIImage?
}
```

your main array will be :  `var arrayofData = [Container]()`

Now when you are query your objects from parse, inside of your query function

```
// after you called the findObjectsWithBackgroundBlock()
// let's assume you check for error and if the [PFObject] is empty or not 

 for one in objectsFromParse
 {
  let photoToget = one["Photo"] as! PFFile
 // next step should be to get the image data right :) 
 {
    // let's assume that is the block when get the image data right:)
    // check your data and assign it to some UIImage
     // then 
     let userRepresentation = Container()  //<-- we are creating a single object representation for each user 

     let username = one["username"] as! String    //<--data we got from Parse
     let companyName = one["companyName"] as! String
     let userImage = //the UIImage which contains the data 

     userRepresentation.username = username
     userRepresentation.companyName = companyName
     userRepresentation.photo = userImage

  // then we append 
    arrayOfData.append(userRepresentation)
 }
}
```

Now we have all data into our array, so let's **filter** by username and also I hope you configure your tableView so when you have data from filter or regular array.

```
  var filterArray = [Container]()  //<-- globally declared

  func search(text: String) -> Void
 {
    filterArray = arrayOfData.filter(){ (Container) -> Bool in
       let range = Container.name!.rangeOfString(text,   options:NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) return range != nil }
       // then you are good to go 
 }
```

Comment: I'm pleased that I managed to do some of the above myself, these examples really helped fill in the gaps. I have added a User class and successfully populated an array of Users. The only trouble I'm having is setting the cell.usernameTextLabel.Text to the relevant user. How can I reference just the username for each User instance? It's currently throwing an error.... I may have just worked it out...one sec!

Comment: are you using this method, or your original one

Comment: I'm using your method, it's going to take a while to implement fully but I'd like to get the logic working today if possible. I'm using the following syntax to try to populate the label but I'm currently receiving the good ol' Array index out of range. cell.usernameCell.text = filterArray[indexPath.row].name

Comment: can you update the code in the question so we could see where is the error

Comment: I've updated the code in the question, I think it covers everything

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using parse, the 'unwrappedSuccess' is just the parse findObjectsInBackground results. I have left out the code which isn't related to the filter function

Comment: All the relevant search and tableView delegates/datasources are there and working perfectly well, do you need me to put them in the question's code? The good news is the table populating correctly when using cell.usernameCell.text = userArray[indexPath.row].name. The filter does not seem to be correctly populating the filterArray. And yes I am reloading the tableView, this is when it is throwing the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100868/discussion-between-lamar-and-ben-sullivan).

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr1 = [10,20,40]
let e1 = arr1.enumerate()
let arr2 = ["a","b","c"]
let f1 = e1.filter { $0.element % 20 == 0 }
let f2 = arr2.enumerate().filter { j, _ in
    f1.contains { i, _ in
        i == j
    }
}

print(f1.map{$0.element}, f2.map{$0.element})
// [20, 40] ["b", "c"]
```

now you have both arrays "filtered". the best, what you can do is redesigning your data model!